# Rails tire gem filtering results in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter, rubygems, tire

Is it possible to post filter a query with elasticsearch tire gem in the controller?
I have a product model wich has a self.search method which is returning an array of results,
but i want for some cases filtering the result in the controller.

ex: when the `current_user.location` is 'London' i only want to display products in london.
is it possible to do that?

```
if current_user.location == 'london'
@products = Product.search(params).results.filter('location:london')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to filter the array of objects after the fact would be very inefficient and slow.  It would also make it very hard to do pagination properly.  You'd be much better off searching and filtering first (so that ElasticSearch is doing the work), and then calling results.

```
Product.search(params).filter(:terms, :location => ['london']).results
```

https://github.com/karmi/retire#usage